# Illegal string offset even though I already decoded array in controller?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, view

I get an array out of a form that could look like this example:

```
array [
  "absender" => "Maxim Ivan",
  "email" => "maximivan@example.com",
  "telefon" => "1234567890",
  "fax" => null,
  "grund" => "Gehaltserhöhung",
  "termin" => [
      0 => [
        "person" => "Some Name",
        "meeting" => "10.05"  
      ],
      1 => [
        "person" => "Another Name",
        "meeting" => "18.05"  
      ],
      2 => [
        "person" => "Again another name",
        "meeting" => null,
        "next-possible-meeting" => "1"  
      ],
      3 => [
        "person" => "And again",
        "meeting" => null,
        "next-possible-meeting" => "1"  
      ],
      4 => [
        "meeting" => null,
  ],
  "bemerkung" => "some notes by Maxim"
]
```

I encoded the array to make it accessible in the `upload`-method like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ json_encode($arrayData) }}" name="array" />
```

in the `upload`-method I have a validation (http request) class as the $request parameter, so I get the array and directly decode it like this:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
```

I give the `$array` to the blade view but when I'm trying to access it to display the values like this:

```
// controller
return view('view', compact('array));

// blade view
@if (isset($array) && !empty($array))
   @foreach ($array as $key => $data)
      <tr>
         @if (!empty($data) && !is_numeric($key))
           <td>{{ $key }}:</td>
           <td>{{ $data[$key] }}</td>
         @else
           <td>{{ $key }}:</td>
           <td>keine Angabe.</td>
         @endif
      </tr>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

I get the error `Illegal string offset 'absender'` but I really don't understand why, I already decoded it in the controller.. Or do I have to decode it *again* in the view?

I am confused.

Comment: Because for `absender`, `$key` is absender, `$data` is `Maxim Ivan`, and calling `$data['absender']` on the string `Maxim Ivan` makes no sense.

Comment: @Jonnix Do I need another foreach then?

Comment: Replace `$data[$key]` with `$data`, but you'll need to do another loop if you're intending on dealing with the `termin` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$data[$key] is a problem..**

When you traverse your loop,

> $key = "absender",
>
> $data = "Maxim Ivan"

And in your blade, you are writing code as $data[$key], which is trying to find out "Maxim Ivan" as an array which is having key as "absender".

**Which is not true in your case!**

you can check before that line that data is an array or not by doing this:

> **is_array($data);**

if it return true then handle array case by looping again to fetch required value and if it returns false then print $data directly.

Hope it solves your issue!

Comment: This helped me getting the right solution, I got it working now, thank you :)